# Fetching data from local server of Android to a website

Tags: php, android, html, google-maps-api-3

I have Google maps project. I am developing both Android application and website.

I have developed Android app now and I am working on website using Google Maps api v3.

I want to get data from local Wamp server and want to show it on the website.. How to do this?

Comment: like i have "hazard reporting" feature in android app, now i want to show this hazard feature on my website.. how to do this...
P.S: i have developed my website using Maps Api v3

Comment: you need to explain your question clearly, unable to understand what you are trying to achieve, if you want help you need to be clear.

Comment: i have a android navigation based project in which whenever an hazard(accident,roadblock)occurs the user will report the hazard and it will mark/draw on google maps. Now i want to develop an website of my this android app and want to show this hazard on website as well.Now how can i fetch data of hazard from Wamp server and show it on my website. P.s: i am using google maps api v3 for website

Comment: In Android, whenever a hazard occurs what information you get about a particular Hazard like (latitude, Longitude ...) etc. ?

Comment: And when you do have the hazard info, what will you do with the info ? send to server ?

Comment: yeah when we have hazard info(like lat&long) then we mark/draw this lat/long as a hazard on google maps

Comment: thats where webservices come into action. use simple php to create webservice and send those lat long to you web server where those lat long gets save into database. Then simply fetch those and draw a marker on web app

Answer (score 0):

For communicating your app with server you must have to create webservice.
either json or xml services.
after that your android app can send or retrive the data from the server using webservices. So try to learn **webservices.**